# Is there a polynomial version of Wilson's theorem which can avoid Cramer flavored conjectures?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Wilson's theorem states that a natural number $n > 1$ is a prime number if and only if the product of all the positive integers less than $n$ is one less than a multiple of $n$.

Is there a version of the theorem in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z[t]$ where $p$ is a prime?

Are there any other non-trivial versions?

My motivation is the following.

There is no efficient algorithm for primes without Cramer's conjecture and so perhaps working with irreducible polynomials avoids **conjectures** and so is finding irreducibles in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z[t]$ any easier?

Comment: From an algebraic point of view, Wilson's Theorem is the observation that the product of all the elements of the units group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times \cong C_{p-1}$ is the unique involution, namely $-1$, while taking the product of nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ gives $0$, because the ring is not an integral domain. You could run this same argument in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[t]$ modulo an ideal.

Comment: What is "algorithm for primes"?

Comment: Guess $x$ and check by $AKS$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) and if not prime check $x+1$ and so on until Cramer's conjecture guarantees. The motivation is to utilize a single prime $p$ (say $2$).

Comment: As Mark says, there is a Wilson's theorem for polynomials. I'm not sure what you want of it regarding avoiding Cramer type conjectures, the usual Wilson's theorem doesn't have anything to do with them.

Comment: As for the last question (which I have no idea what it has to do with Wilson's theorem) - $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z[t]$ has irreducible polynomials of any positive degree $n$, which is the closest analogue to Cramer I can think of (it is known unconditionally though). For some algorithms for that, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/105543/30186)

Comment: Is there an efficient deterministic algorithm to get irreducible polynomial of degree $k$? As far as I can infer the answer accepted there has the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1642 which has randomized algorithm. So the Cramer barrier to deterministic approach appears in one way or another.